# Inject content from <template> into <slot>

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element, html-templates

I want to get template content, inject it into a custom element with shadow DOM and apply styles to `span` inside `template` via `::slotted` selector but this doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <template id="template">
            <span>element from template</span>
        </template>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            class WithShadowDom extends HTMLElement {
                constructor() {
                    super();
                    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
                    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
                        <style>
                            ::slotted(span) {
                                font-size: 25px;
                            }
                        </style>
                    `;
                    shadowRoot
                        .appendChild(document.createElement('slot'))
                        .appendChild(
                            document.getElementById('template').content.cloneNode(true)
                        );
                }
            }
            window.customElements.define('with-shadow-dom', WithShadowDom);
            const myCustomElement = document.createElement('with-shadow-dom');
            document.body.appendChild(myCustomElement);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The below piece doesn't work as expected. The `font-size` css doesn't get applied.

```
shadowRoot
    .appendChild(document.createElement('slot'))
    .appendChild(document.getElementById('template').content.cloneNode(true));
```

While when directly appending a child `span` inside custom element the `font-size` gets applied.

```
const span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = 'asdffad';
shadowRoot
    .appendChild(document.createElement('slot'))
    .appendChild(span);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've appended the span to the shadow dom. You should add it to the light dom instead if you want it to be inserted in the `<slot>` place.

```
connectedCallback() {
    //template content
    this.appendChild(document.getElementById('template').content.cloneNode(true));
    //span element
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = 'asdffad';
    this.appendChild(span);
}
```

NB: you should not append some content to the light DOM in the `constructor()`. Instead do it in the `connectedCallback()` method.

When you look at the *Elements* pane in the Developer console, you can see that the result is different when you add an HTML fragment or element to `<slot>` and to the light DOM.

Comment: But I am appending the `span` as a child of `slot` not directly as a child of `shadowRoot`, so it actually is added to the light DOM. Besides, I am not complaining about the behaviour of `span`, it works as I expect, my question is about the `template`. The `span` element inside `template` doesn't take style defined in `::slotted(span)`

Comment: @YuriyKravets no you cannot add something (a template content or a span) to the light DOM through the <slot> element. It won't work. You should add it to the light dom directly.